# What adapter do I need to replace 2 AA lithium batteries?

Tags: power-supply

Does anyone know what the amperage rating for Energizer lithium non-charging batteries is so I can source an appropriate AC adapter, or could anyone provide an appropriate adapter specification?

I have a device that runs on two 1.5 V Energizer lithium non-charging batteries, but they only last about a week, so I want to convert it to an ac adapter. However, when seeking the power requirements for the device, the manufacture would only say that it only runs with lithium batteries.

When checking the Energizer specs for the batteries, they say they have an open circuit voltage of 1.8 V which drops to around 1.5 V under load, but no current rating. I tried my device with a 3 V 1 A adapter, and it partially works, but not correctly. So, rather than trying random adapters, does anyone know what the battery characteristic is?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here. Peak current could be an issue, but AA’s aren’t known for supplying more than 1 A for very long.

Comment: You can look up details on a [datasheet](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/l91.pdf). You should be able to see that if you are getting about a week on them, then they are drawing about 15 mA. Fairly low draw. In almost no case would 3 V be a problem, though. They only sustain a higher voltage at about 1 mA. And that's doubtful. So your 3 V adapter (if it is a good one) should be fine. The fact that you are having problems means you need to get out a meter and take some measurements for us, with the lithium batteries and the system active as well as with the adapter.

Comment: Ideally, when troubleshooting this you’d have a bench supply and use it to vary the voltage and max current until you found a stable range. If you don’t have that, you can try finding a discrete 3.3V 1A supply and a 3V 2A supply and see what changes under all three supplies. Also keep in mind that most discrete supplies you find online are junk and don’t always honor their printed specs. A good starting point is making sure the supplies are UL listed.

Comment: "recommendation" is a poison word here, giving an excuse for closing any question. "Consumer products" also are an excuse for closing questions. So I've edited your question to remove the obvious excuses for closing the question. You can try again and see if you get any actual answers to the actual question.

Comment: Current energizer lithium AAs  an source 2.5A max current. And barely changes the capacity of ~3.3Ah. And it will be much cleaner than a random power supply. You could use a nicer supply, and/or regulate whatever supply down with a linear regulator and proper filter caps, at a higher possible amperage. Running a PS above 80% max AND below 10% draw tends to cause gremlins. As for the behavior, a mechanical doorbell is a motor and would need a higher surge current. The camera draw, use an ammeter to get the steady draw. Or just throw a 2 amp supply at it.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of proper documentation from the manufacturer, the way to find out its voltage and current requirements would be to use a "bench PSU" so that you could vary the voltage (within reason) and measure the current drawn when the doorbell camera is working properly.

At a pair of AA lithium cells per week, it would be even be financially sensible to get a 3 A bench PSU under, say, $60, and you'll end up with both a bench PSU and the knowledge of which fixed-voltage mains adapter you need.

(Having said that, 3.3 V, 1 A mains adapters are available.)